# asp.net tabindex not working

Tags: asp.net

iam using tabindex in asp.net form 2.0in IE, it is not working at all....any idea how to make it right.. your help will be appreciated

Comment: How are implementing it? What version of IE?

Comment: It would help if you post some of your markup and explain exactly how it is not working the way you expect.

Comment: hi, iam just assigning tab index.. to text box n text area.. it still soemwhat working in chrome.. but in IE..its not even working a bit... textbox with multiline is giving problem as tab is not going there..

Comment: Thanks but I'm still going to need to see some markup to be able to help you.

Comment: Are you using any controls or javascript libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Use tabindex="0" for all controls. Checked in IE 8 & 7 only.